# Query to select a row of table returns null and undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-query, supabase

I have a react app which uses supabase as its database.
this is my table:
[image]
I have set the RLS policies to read and update for all users.
In the other hand, this is my react app codes:
Query function:
[image]
Custom hook:
[image]
and my functional component:
[image]
But i get this error:
[image]

I tried to select and get my table's single row, but i got null or undefined.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code examples, paste them directly here with the correct formatting.

You didn't show what any of your RLS policies look like, have you tested this with RLS turned off? to be sure that the issue is RLS related. If it works with RLS turned off then it's your policy not being met or your user isn't logged in.